Android PWA opens with the port 3000 when opening from Google Chrome
we are developing an application as a PWA, built with Bubblewrap, that we have in Google Play right now.
The problem is that for the testers who use Google Chrome as the default browser, the URL that is opening, sometimes contains the port 3000 that we didn't specify at all. We still don't know when exactly the ":3000" part is filled in the URL. We tried it on the 3rd device an hour ago and it worked fine, suddenly, but the functionality is not for granted.
For me, as a Firefox user, the problem never happened.
Has anybody encountered this issue?
Here are the screenshots from three individual devices (the app should start on apps.oppi.ai/chat or chat.oppi.ai/chat, but it opens apps.oppi.ai:3000 or chat.oppi.ai:3000 respectively):
dev. 1

dev. 2

dev. 3

Here's my device (with Firefox as the default browser):
dev. 4

I would like the app to be working on devices with Google Chrome as the default browser.

It seems that your issue might have to do with Chrome automatically mapping the url to the https:// protocol.
Navigating to your URL in any browser with protocol https:// and port :3000 will produce the results you're showing.
Editing your .htaccess file to enable automatic redirecting could help fix this.
